# How do I order my SQL results in the same order of my query (a sentence broken down into a tuple of words)?

Tags: python, mysql

Using Python I would like to get results from a dictionary table in the same order of a query that I give it.
I supply the query with a tuple as a broken down sentence (could I do this in an ordered list such as an array?).
I'm using a standard MySQLdb cursor (should I try a different one?) and using it to execute a query as follows:

```
import MySQLdb
...

sent_tuple = ('The', 'opening', 'session', 'of', 'the', '5-day', 'session', 'will', 'begin', 'at', '10', 'a.m.', 'today', '.')
mysql_cursor = mysql.cursor()
query = ("SELECT DISTINCT Orthography, Transcription FROM Dictionary WHERE Orthography IN " + sent_tuple + " ORDER BY FIELD(Transcription, Orthography)")
for rows in mysql_cursor:
    print rows
```

The results come out, not in the same order as given in the sent_tuple, but more or less in ascending alphabetic order, which I guess is the default for SELECT statements...:

```
('AT', 'AE T')
('BEGIN', 'B IH G IH N')
('OF', 'AH V')
('OPENING', 'OW P AH N IH NG')
('SESSION', 'S EH SH AH N')
('THE', 'DH AH')
('TODAY', 'T AH D EY')
('WILL', 'W IH L')
('.', '.')
```

There are also some missing results where there is no match from the dictionary. Not sure how to handle this... Directions??

I've looked at some of the similar posts here at the StackExchange, e.g. involving ORDER BY, but can't seem to get them to work...

Comment: How long will your tuples get?  (i.e. how many words are you processing at a time?)

Comment: Maybe between 2 - 25 items long?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's possible to do it in SQL, but you can certainly use the original input tuple as the index for traversing the results:

```py
from collections import OrderedDict

sent_tuple = ('The', 'opening', 'session', 'of', 'the', '5-day', 'session', 'will', 'begin', 'at', '10', 'a.m.', 'today', '.')
rows = [
    ('AT', 'AE T'),
    ('BEGIN', 'B IH G IH N'),
    ('OF', 'AH V'),
    ('OPENING', 'OW P AH N IH NG'),
    ('SESSION', 'S EH SH AH N'),
    ('THE', 'DH AH'),
    ('TODAY', 'T AH D EY'),
    ('WILL', 'W IH L'),
    ('.', '.'),
]

index = OrderedDict.fromkeys( i.upper() for i in sent_tuple ) 
rows_dict = dict(rows)
ordered_rows_gen = (
    (i, rows_dict[i]) for i in index if i in rows_dict
)

for row in ordered_rows_gen:
    print row
```

I've created the `index` as an `OrderedDict` with the input tuple values as the keys, as this provides a quick ordered set and will avoid any duplicates in the output.